# Attach event to Sharepoint multi-line textbox having text type "Enhance Rich Text"

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, dom-events, richtextbox, multiline

I have to attach `OnKeyPress` event to the SharePoint multi-line column with **text type as "Enhance Rich Text"**. Following is the jscript code that I am using

```
<script>

    var ele=document.getElementById(inpID);
       
     if(ele!=null){
     ele.onkeypress=function(){calLen(this);};
    }

function calLen(obj)
{

  if(obj.value.length>=5){
   alert('Cannot exceed character limit 5');
      obj.value=obj.value.substring(0,5);
}

</script>
```

But the event is not getting attached.

The things are working fine with SharePoint Multi-line TextBox **with Text Type as "Plain Text"**.

Can some one help me to solve this issue...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhanced Rich Text fields are not rendered as any sort of standard `FORM` control (like, for instance, a simple `TEXTAREA`). They are complex controls comprised of, among other things, an `IFRAME` that can display your HTML content preview.

I recommend using Internet Explorer's [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) (or even better, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Mozilla Firefox) to drill in to the E.R.T. "control" and figure out what subcomponents you could bind to.

Also, it's entirely possible that some events, like `onkeypress`, are already being handled internally to the E.R.T. and thus will never bubble up so that you can handle them.

If you're using a replacement component for your E.R.T. (esp. [Telerik's RADEditor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx)), there may be some custom events that have been implemented and to which you could bind to.